# In Ecommerce tracking, Is there a way to send a custom variable with each item to Google Analytics servers?

Tags: google-analytics

I want to send the author name of every purchased book as custom variable in the Ecommerce transaction:

```
_gaq.push(
    ['_addItem',
        'Nº 1000',
        '90661',
        'Some nice book',
        'Category: Design',
        '54.00','2'
    ]);
_gaq.push(
    ['_addItem',
        'Nº 1000',
        '105568',
        'Another nice book',
        'Category: Arquitecture',
        '75.00',
        '7'
    ]);
```

Here is when things get complicated. I tried to add a *_setCustomVar* push after the end of each *addItem* but Google catch only the last pushed value -and that how it's supposed to be, but I don't find a way to achieve what I want.

Is actually possible to send a custom variable for every item in the ecommerce transaction?

Thanks for all the ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so - as you have tested it does not work in code and that products do not support dimension widening seems to be a strong indicator that you cannot easily add information to products (it would be interesting to see if products support custom dimensions in Universal Analytics, which might provide a way out - you'll have to switch anyway some time soon. I'll test this and get back to you. However I do not think some, for the same reasons stated above).

Comment: I'll give a look at Universal Analytics and custom dimentions. I was thinking that sending custom variables -if I could find a way to do it- with addtional info about each product doesn't would be useful if later want to reverse the ecommerce transaction.